# Blurry UILabel when added programmatically

Tags: ios, ios5, uilabel, blurry

I am adding a UILabel to a view meant for loading purposes. However, it gets blurry after I added it.
The weird thing is that I just about the same code for an loading view which is loaded ontop of an UITableViewController and it works great there. Yet, this one on top of an UIViewController is blurry.

This is my code:

```
float x = (self.view.frame.size.width-20)/2;
float y = (self.view.frame.size.height-70)/2;

// Add loading and sub text
UILabel *loadingText = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, round(y+30), round(self.view.frame.size.width-20), 21)];
[loadingText setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
[loadingText setNumberOfLines:0];
[loadingText setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17]];
[loadingText setText:NSLocalizedString(@"Please wait...\nWe are processing your request", @"LoadingPage")];
[loadingText sizeToFit];
[loadingText setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[loadingText setCenter:self.view.center];
[loadingText setTag:2];

[view addSubview:loadingText];
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Your label is blurry because the frame is using floating numbers.

To force integers value for your frame just do :

```
[loadingText setFrame:CGRectIntegral(loadingText.frame)];
```

You could also cast all your values composing your frame to `int`, but `CGRectIntegral` does all the job for you.

Comment: `#define CGPointIntegral(point) CGPointMake((int)point.x,(int)point.y)` is a quick macro to cast CGPoint members to integers.

Comment: What about rotated labels? They still appear blurry even using an integral frame (as expected, it becomes non-integral): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492367/how-do-i-achieve-a-clearly-rendered-rotated-uilabel

Comment: Didn't work for me... Do all superviews need to be laid out with `CGRectIntegral`?

Comment: Hi NSZombie Event adding CGRectIntegral I am getting Blurred text.

Comment: Try to laid out the superview containing your label. If the superview itself is using float, your label might be blurred (although I never saw this kind of behaviour).

Comment: Worked for me, and of course, you can save yourself a line (if that's important to you) by using CGRectIntegral directly in the UILabel initialisation: `initWithFrame:CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(yourXpos, yourYpos, yourWidth, yourHeight))`

Comment: +1 worked for me. Even if container views are floating values lables et blurred.

Comment: How would I do this if I'm using autolayout because won't autolayout ignore my manually set frame?

Answer (score 16):

Apart from the float/int issue, calling `setShouldRasterize` on the parent view of the UILabel can also cause this problem to appear.

Comment: This is what fixed it for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For those of you that couldn't use the previous answers, I found that if I turned off the `autoresizingmask` feature it called the `setShouldRasterize` method.

```
[loadingText setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

thus if you comment this line out, it will display correctly

Comment: In my case, I have to apply this one and the accepted answer simultaneously.