# Why do my iOS fonts look very pixelated? Best font for iOS7?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I pick Helvetica Neue UltraLight in IB, and it really looks pretty terrible. Is there a best setting for built in iOS fonts or are all the beautiful fonts all custom imports?

Best background color, font, shadow offset, size?  That works for you, i.e, your favorite settings or fonts.

[image]

Simple label. iPad screen shot, non-retina.

Comment: Does the font look pixelated in IB or in the simulator? I don't think it's an issue with font. Something else is wrong....

Comment: On the iPad. It's ok, but still some pixelation. Not sure what else can be going on. Will get an image up.

Comment: are you changing frame of your label with code?

Comment: All done in storyboards. No code. Dropping label on a view with a light gray background and setting alpha 7.5 for just the view so background just shows through.

Comment: Helvetica Neue UltraLight has always looked pretty terrible at small sizes IMO. It's a font made for headlines. Also keep in mind iOS does not have subpixel antialiasing, so text is bound to not be great on non-retina displays (especially very thin fonts).

Comment: iOS does have sub-pixel anti-aliasign - the issue comes from using attempting to alpha-blend a layer with text in it as the text is pre-rendered in a CoreAnimation layer without knowledge of the potentially transparent items behind and in front in the layer stack.

Comment: Not sure why, weird, the accept an answer arrow is gone. I'm sure it's totally obvious, but trying accept your answer and no arrow to click.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had the same issue and i took me a couple of hours to find out.
So the main issue is that the label or the label parent frame/center is using floating numbers.
 you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8066531/2050181) and [this](http://blog.corywiles.com/fixing-blurry-text-in-ios)

My problem was that i have added shadow to parent layer and i had this line `self.tabsView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;` 
but after removing it the pixeled/blured effect was gone.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks, I'm all Swift now. This is a great tip. All issues solved. :-)

Comment: Yes! Thanks infinite for this answer! I've been racking my brain on what is automagically controlling the label/font of a button I'm using, and some existing developers apparently have set the entire parent view to "shouldRasterize"! I had zero clue as to what was going on ... googling "swift3 blurry pixelated font" brought me here ... thanks again!

Comment: @ChrisAllinson glad that it helped :)