# iOS simulator looking fuzzy and pixelated

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, simulator

After upgrading to Xcode 7.2 the iOS simulator looks fuzzy and pixelated. The simulator version is 9.2.

Simulator Screenshot:

[image: imulator Screenshot]

Comment: Scale it to 100%. Clearly your simulator is being shown at less than 100% since because it won't fit on your computer's screen.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy. But how to make it look normal then? I mean normal size.

Comment: As I said, scale it to 100%. Simulator -> Window -> Scale

Comment: @rmaddy I did. After which it has width and heigh of almost half the screen of iMac 27"

Comment: Right. Those are your two choices. 1) Nice and clear but too big to fit on the screen, or 2) Fuzzy but scaled small enough to see the whole thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do my iOS fonts look very pixelated? Best font for iOS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053892/why-do-my-ios-fonts-look-very-pixelated-best-font-for-ios7)

Answer (score 6):

Go into debug and untick the "Optimize Rendering for Window Scale" option

[image]

Comment: This worked 1 year ago, doesn't work for newer versions of the iOS simulator.

Comment: My simulator was like those oldschool tv's that had grey screen with pixels everywhere, no idea why. This fixed it ... should be accepted answer

Comment: Doesn't work since Xcode 8. We are now in Xcode 9.1, and the issue still persists.

Comment: We are aware of this issue

Answer (score 0):

Showing on external **non-retina** display may also seem fuzzy.