# Xcode 9 simulator looks terrible

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode9

It's extremely pixelated, aliasing is terrible, see below, yuck!

I'm running on Sierra, 2015 rMBP, external Apple Display.

Is there a way to fix it? Without success, I've tried:

1. Scaling to 100%
2. Turning on/off `Debug > Optimize Rendering for Window Scale` (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36431207/45813))
3. `Debug > Graphics Quality Override > High Quality`

[image: 1997 called and wants its graphics back!]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 100% sizing in Xcode 9 has a bug where it considers 3x devices to be 2x for scaling. Manually resize the device larger and it should clear up.

Comment: I took "manually resize" to mean grab a corner and pull to make it bigger. That worked. _Still!_

Comment: We are aware of this issue

Comment: @russbishop can you provide a link to a bug tracker? I'm having issues with a particular simulator device only. iPhone 8 iOS 12.1 .

Comment: Use https://bugreport.apple.com. It is usually helpful if you include the bug report number (radar number) in your reply so I can look it up directly.