# How to remove pixelated text and make it smooth?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have some numbers written with drawinRect . But the numbers seems to be pixelated. How to smoothen its edges?

[image: Pixelated dates]

The code used for this is:

```
   [date drawInRect:CGRectMake(targetX+2, targetY+10, kVRGCalendarViewDayWidth, kVRGCalendarViewDayHeight) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:10] lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
```

Comment: please provide more code its not enough to find the problem

Comment: This might have been answered here (by NSZombie): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065892/blurry-uilabel-when-added-programatically

"The frame is using float numbers".

Try adding `setFrame:CGRectIntegral`to your frame

Comment: Sometimes drawing can appear fuzzy on the simulator, but looks great on a device; try it out on a device and see if it looks okay